# NUnit Chrome Driver without path

Tags: visual-studio-2010, selenium-webdriver, nunit, selenium-chromedriver

I am creating Selenium test using Chrome Driver. To run test on my machine, I run Chrome Driver from the path in my computer like,

```
Instance = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\..\);
```

But the point is, if somebody want to run my test using NUnit, it doesn't work because the path of the Driver is the one associated to my machine no to the machine that the other person is using. 
So, is it possible somehow to attach the Driver to the project without writing path and be able to run in all machines without changing anything?

Comment: Add it as part of your project, ensuring it's set to be Copied on build. Then point your `ChromeDriver` instance to that, using the `Path` class in the .NET framework to correctly walk the tree of the project. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think I found a solution, addig the chromeDriver to my project, and after in properties I set up as Embedded resource and "copy always" It looks it works

Answer (score 1):

I have not used NUnit. But I understand your issue & This is how i do.

I use TestNG framework to run my selenium-webdriver regression scripts. I run the scripts periodically using jenkins in different slave machines (windows/mac). Chrome and IE driver servers are part of my project. (i just added to my project folder). I find the absolute path to these drivers @ runtime and use it to start the service. So this way it does NOT depend on the machines or users who runs it. It works great. I would suggest you the same!